# reference to php session variable resolving as a variable in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
window.companyID=<?php echo $_SESSION['IDCompany']; ?>;
window.userID=<?php echo $_SESSION['IDUser']; ?>;
window.sLevel=<?php echo $_SESSION['SLevel']; ?>;
```

The first two resolve to their appropriate values. But the last one is doing something javascript doesn't like for some reason. When the page loads, the console log gives me the following error right after I assign the variable:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: S1 is not defined.

"S1" is the correct value. However, it seems as if javascript thinks S1 is a variable, though I have no idea. I tried forcing JS to treat it as a string but that did not work. No matter what I do, the immediate result of the assignment always produces the error.

Any ideas why this would happen to this particular session variable and not the previous two?

Comment: Look at the *generated* HTML/JavaScript and you will see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your other two SESSION variables return integers... You're getting this error because you are returning a string in this one, and thus it should be between single quotes:

```
window.sLevel='<?php echo $_SESSION['SLevel']; ?>';
```

Comment: you nailed it. Knew it was gonna be something small and stupid. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a string, you have to wrap the value in quotes:

```
window.sLevel='<?php echo $_SESSION['SLevel']; ?>';
//            ^                                  ^
```

The other two variables are IDs, so I guess they're just numbers (which don't have to be quoted), so you're good with those.